# GatsbyJS: How to store an array in a markdown file?

Tags: yaml, markdown, gatsby

Suppose I have the following index.md in my Gatsby app:

```
---
title: "Names"
numberOfNames: "3"
---
```

Now I would like to add an array of separate names like "Alex", "Bill", "Jack" under "names" tag.

How would I represent that array in a markdown file so that later I could iterate over it in my .js file?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

frontmatter use yaml syntax. You can declare an array like so:

```
names:
  - Alex
  - Ben
  - ...
```

or

```
names: ['Alex', 'Ben', ...]
```